# Correct way of storing Contacts related data in a Windows Store app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to build a chat app and I want to manage the user's contact list.Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of storing Contact information(username,alias) in Windows Store app?
In my other app(already published in Windows Phone store),I have used SQLite as database backend for storing such data but I read somewhere that SQLite is not recommended for Window Store apps. What do you use for storing such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in using SQLite in windows phone store apps and also it is recommended because of its fast data retrieval/save operations as indexes can be applied on the column.

other option for storing data in windows phone app is JSON(using json.net or other libraries). The drawback of using Json files is that it will be slow in large data as all the jason file will be loaded in memory and even if you need only one record from a large data set.

In your case I will recommend SQLite as the contacts will be more with other relational data link phone and address etc. You can easily use joins to retrieve relation data from SQLite tables.

Comment: He can create a Repository class which handles the loading of data from the disk, so he gets the benefits (and ease) of JSON without having to load all data in at the same time.

Comment: Actually SQLite is the preferred way for storing data on a local database.